# Parse Android SDK issue

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I'm developing an app which use Parse SDK. It was working a years ago, but now it is not working and crashing. 
Also I was debugging on Android studio 2.2.3 and I could debug the app but when I generated apk file and installed it on phone, the app crashed.
When I debugging on android studio 2.3.3, it crashed and couldn't debug it.

Here is the log of crash

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.steaklocker.steaklocker, PID: 2308
>                                                                              java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void bolts.Task.()' is
>   inaccessible to class 'bolts.TaskCompletionSource' (declaration of
>   'bolts.TaskCompletionSource' appears in
>   /data/app/com.steaklocker.steaklocker-1/base.apk:classes10.dex)
>                                                                                  at bolts.TaskCompletionSource.(TaskCompletionSource.java:18)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.parse.ParseTaskUtils.callbackOnMainThreadAsync(ParseTaskUtils.java:100)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.parse.ParseTaskUtils.callbackOnMainThreadAsync(ParseTaskUtils.java:72)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.parse.ParseTaskUtils.callbackOnMainThreadAsync(ParseTaskUtils.java:59)
>                                                                                  at com.parse.ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(ParsePush.java:264)
>                                                                                  at com.xxx.xxx.xxxApplication.onCreate(SteaklockerApplication.java:65)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4553)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Here is the relational information on grade.

```
compileSdkVersion = 22
buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"
minSdkVersion = 21
targetSdkVersion = 23

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1'
compile 'com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1'
compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.3@aar'
```

Comment: Current version is com.parse:parse-android:1.15.8, Can you try with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an old version of parse sdk.
Try with the new version, like this:

```
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0') {
    exclude module: 'bolts-android'
}
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.15.6'
compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.4@aar'
```

And in your application:

```
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .clientBuilder(builder)
            .clientKey("clientkey")
            .server("https://server.com/parse")
            .build());
```